# 2002 Nissin Altima 2.5SL - repair/replace a fuel level sensor function-slosh

Tags: nissan, altima

Multiple Questions

How do I find where the fuel level senor function-slosh is located?

How do I replace it?

How could I possibly repair it on a 2002 Nissan Altima 2.5SL?

Answer (score 1):

The level sensor is in the gas tank. Its part of the fuel pump assembly.
Repairing it requires you to lower the fuel tank, remove the assembly, and install a new assembly altogether. Won't be easy or cheap. Save your back and take it to a mechanic. Have them check the dash gauge before replacing the sensor.